# How to change view controller everyday at specific time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a case where a user needs to submit a form everyday before 8am.

When they submit, a confirmation view is overlaid to show the user they have submitted as well as stop them from submitting again.

After 8am, I want to clear the form and have the form view available again by hiding the overlaid view.  I want to do this at one point in time at 8am if possible.

I was thinking about accomplishing this with `NSTimer`.  Can I set a timer that will run at 8am that will clear the form and remove the overlay view?

Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a local push notification. Official doc here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Something like that:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date]; // Replace me with your "event" date
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

then you can "catch" the notification as the doc says

> If your app is frontmost, the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or *application:didReceiveLocalNotification:method* is called on its app delegate If your app is not frontmost or not running you handle the notifications by checking the options dictionary passed to the *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* of your app delegate for either the *UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey* or UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey key.

You can't use just a NSTimer, because it will not run when your app is closed, however another solution that involves NSTimer is to create a NSTimer for the event date, and then observe *UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification*, here if the timer is running, you'll stop the timer, persisting the timer.fireDate (you can save it in NSUserDefault for example), finally observing *UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification*, you can recreate the timer (substracting the current time with the value that you saved previously) or just fire the action if the event time already passed on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a UILocalNotification you can dynamically define your initial view controller (VC) by:

- Programmatically loading the VC in `didFinishLoadingWithOptions:` in `AppDelegate`
- Or subclass your `UINavigationController` and set your rootController dynamically